# @target the name 'target' does not exist in the current context Provider Hosted App

Tags: provider-hosted-app, mvc

I am combining a MVC 5 SharePoint Provider Hosted App together with pages with just javascript. I created a page with the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var hostweburl;
    var appweburl;

    $(document).ready(function () {


        //Get the URI decoded URLs.
        hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
        appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

        // resources are in URLs in the form:
        // web_url/_layouts/15/resource
        var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

        // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
        // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
            function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js",
                    function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", InitForm); }
                    );
            }
        );

    });

    function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
        var params =
            document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
        var strParams = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
    // prepare the data
    function InitForm() {
        var json;
        // executor: The RequestExecutor object
        // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

        var completeUrl = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('Ploegen')/items?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";


        var testSource = executor.executeAsync({
            url: completeUrl,
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("error: " + data.statusText);
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("succes: " + data.d.results);
                        json = data.d.results
                    }
                }).responseText;



    }
</script>
```

The only problem is that when I run the script I got the message the name 'target' does not exist in the current context.

HostWebUrl and WebAppUrl are filled, but still getting @target errors, even when I am only creating a string with @target init.

What am I doing wrong, because I don't get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a trick to fix it. Since @target is interpreted by MSIL and not by JS the error CS0103 returns. Compiling and deploying works without issues, but then comes the problem. Even when it is a string it returns CS0103.

So after using: @@target instead of @target the problem resolved. The problem occurs when you use cshtml files instead of *.js files